# Can't access my location on GeoLocation app

Tags: html, location

I started an app to get my location when I click on a button, but my problem is that my browser and other browsers don't permit me to use my location.

I already tried different browsers like Chrome, Edge, Mozilla and none of them gave me permission.

It always says that it is "blocked to protect my privacy"

Here's my code, because I don't know if it has something to do with it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Geolocation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="get_location">Get Localtion</a>

    <div id="map">
        <iframe id="google_map" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>
        var c = function(pos) {
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude, 
                long = pos.coords.longitude,
                coords = lat + "," + long;

            document.getElementById("google_map").setAttribute("src","https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + coords + "&z=60&output=embed");
        }

        document.getElementById("get_location").onclick = function(){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c);
            return false;   
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the "error":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Web Application was connected over HTTPS.

The [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) is restricted to secure origins:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins